# Разбиение 2D массива на столбцы

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

**У меня есть например такой массив:**

```py
[[8.80e+04 9.00e+00]
 [1.05e+05 4.00e+00]
 [1.28e+05 9.00e+00]
 [1.04e+05 9.00e+00]
 [1.00e+05 1.10e+01]
 [8.00e+04 2.00e+00]
 [8.30e+04 9.00e+00]
 [8.10e+04 3.00e+00]
 [5.60e+04 2.00e+00]
 [1.06e+05 5.00e+00]]
```

**И мне нужно разбить его на два массива**

```py
[[8.80e+04]
 [1.05e+05]
 [1.28e+05]
 [1.04e+05]
 [1.00e+05]
 [8.00e+04]
 [8.30e+04]
 [8.10e+04]
 [5.60e+04]
 [1.06e+05]] и

[[9.00e+00]
 [4.00e+00]
 [9.00e+00]
 [9.00e+00]
 [1.10e+01]
 [2.00e+00]
 [9.00e+00]
 [3.00e+00]
 [2.00e+00]
 [5.00e+00]]
```

*Cпасибо за внимание.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный массив:

```
arr = np.array(
[[8.80e+04, 9.00e+00],
 [1.05e+05, 4.00e+00],
 [1.28e+05, 9.00e+00],
 [1.04e+05, 9.00e+00],
 [1.00e+05, 1.10e+01],
 [8.00e+04, 2.00e+00],
 [8.30e+04, 9.00e+00],
 [8.10e+04, 3.00e+00],
 [5.60e+04, 2.00e+00],
 [1.06e+05, 5.00e+00]])
```

Решение:

```
a,b = np.split(arr, [1], axis=1)
```

Результат:

```
In [29]: a
Out[29]:
array([[ 88000.],
       [105000.],
       [128000.],
       [104000.],
       [100000.],
       [ 80000.],
       [ 83000.],
       [ 81000.],
       [ 56000.],
       [106000.]])

In [30]: b
Out[30]:
array([[ 9.],
       [ 4.],
       [ 9.],
       [ 9.],
       [11.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 9.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 5.]])
```

Comment: You are Jesus..